# Underlying datastructure for Dictionary<TKey,TValue> in .net

Tags: c#, .net

What is the underlying data structure for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` in .net? Is it a hashtable?

I have another question, is there any commonly used generic collection that uses a linkedlist as the underlying data structure?

Comment: Dictionary uses a HashTable data structure. `LinkedList<T>` uses a linkedList data structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Dictionary class is a type-safe Hashtable implementation, and strongly types both the keys and values.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary uses an array of entries underneath the covers. The source is available here:

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary@cs/1305376/Dictionary@cs

Comment: It's more complex than *just* an array of entries.  It does use an array, yes, but it's not like it's just an array of `KeyValuePair` objects, or even of just keys or values.

Comment: The Entry structure is detailed in the source code I linked to; the exact underlying structure is an Entry[]. The source is there for all to see how complicated it is or isn't. The specific question was what is the UNDERLYING DATA STRUCTURE.

Comment: Answers on SO should answer the question within the text of the answer and not be reliant on an external links to meaningfully answer the question.  Yes, an array is used as a part of the implementation of the structure, but it's more complex than just that; the answer is missing so much information that it is highly misleading.